# Where to put AWS credentials for daemon user?

Tags: daemon, aws

I have a script that backs up a directory to AWS S3 every night. (The script is run via a systemd timer.) I would like to create a dedicated user for this service. Ordinarily, I would not create a home directory for this user. Where, then, should I put the AWS credentials file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it wherever you like, typically somewhere in `/etc`. In your backup script set `AWS_CONFIG_FILE=...` pointing to that location.

Check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html for more info.

Hope that helps :)